# Tag suggest box library - like in Stackoverflow.com

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt

Here in Stackoverflow.com, while typing-in tags, it can show, a "popup" box that shows all the possible tags that we can use. And if we hit spacebar it inputs that as a tag in the text box.

What is this component made of:

- Is there an opensource library for this in Javascript (preferably Bootstrap)
- Or a Jquery plugin?
- Or in Google web toolkit (GWT) perhaps?

Comment: The 'Multiple Select' thingy in here may help - http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: I assume all the tags are stored in a database somewhere... and it's pretty much just a search bar that performs and AJAX call, it would probably be easy enough to do it without a plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags) It has tagging support.

The code to implement this would look like this.

```
$("#input-ID").select2({
                  tags:["red", "green", "blue"],
                  tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
 });
```